# How should I do a redirect to a path with an object in ember?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-router

I'm trying to put together a data-driven menu system in Ember.js.  Here's the javascript, `js/nodal.js`:

```js
window.Form = Ember.Application.create();

var menuOptions = [
{id: "root",
 options: [ "a", "b" ]},
{id: "a",
      name: "Option A",
 options: [ "c", "d" ]},
{id: "b",
  name: "Option B",
 options: [ "e", "f" ]},
{id: "c",
 name: "Option C"},
{id: "d",
 name: "Option D"},
{id: "e",
 name: "Option E"},
{id: "f",
 name: "Option F"}
]

Form.MenuOption = Ember.Object.extend({});

var builtOptions = menuOptions.map( function(attrs) {
return Form.MenuOption.create( attrs );
});

Form.options = {};
for( i = 0; i < builtOptions.length; i++ ) {
var opt = builtOptions[i];
Form.options[opt.id] = opt;
}

Form.MenuRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
model: function(params){
    console.log( params );
    if( !params || !params.index_id || params.index_id == "undefined") {
    params.index_id = "root";
    }
    var keys = Form.options[params.index_id].options;
    var options = new Array();
    keys.map(function(k){ options.push( Form.options[k] ); });
    return options;
  }    
});

Form.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
redirect: function(){
        /* This here is the problem line... */
    this.transitionTo( "menu", Form.options.root );
}
});

Form.Router.map(function(){
this.resource( "menu", { path: "/menu/:index_id" } );
});
```

And here's the HTML, such as it is:

```
  <title>Hello</title>
  <meta name="description" content="My First Ember.js App">
  <meta name="author" content="Your Name Here">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body>
  <script data-template-name="application" type="text/x-handlebars">
<h1>Title Goes Here</h1>
{{outlet}}
  </script>


  <script data-template-name="menu" type="text/x-handlebars">
<ul>
{{#each controller}}
  <li>{{#linkTo menu this}}{{name}}{{/linkTo}}</li>
{{/each}}
</ul>
  </script>


  <script src="js/libs/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script src="js/libs/handlebars.js"></script>
  <script src="js/libs/ember-1.0.0-rc.1.js"></script>
  <script src="js/nodal.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

What I want is for the user to be redirected to `/menu/root` as soon as they open the page.  So far I haven't been able to find the right incantation to make this work.  When I load the above, I get this exception:

```
Error: assertion failed: an Ember.CollectionView's content must implement Ember.Array. You passed <(generated menu controller):ember172>
```

If I load `index.html#/menu/root` directly, it works - it's only the redirect that's not working.  Replacing the `this.transitionTo` line in the IndexRoute definition with this:

```js
this.transitionTo( "menu", [Form.options.root] );
```

*does* redirect, but it redirects to `/menu/undefined`, not `/menu/root`.  That's ugly, and obviously broken.

What have I missed?

**EDIT**

As suggested, I tried adding an ArrayController:

```
Form.MenuController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({});
```

This gives me a new error:

```
arrangedContent.addArrayObserver is not a function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your URL assumes you are working with one model, but in transitioTo and your model hook your are passing/returning an array. Your MenuRoute is always about **one** MenuOption, right?

Therefore i would suggest:

```
Form.MenuRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
model: function(params){
    console.log( params );
    if( !params || !params.index_id || params.index_id == "undefined") {
    params.index_id = "root";
    }
    var menuOption = Form.options[params.index_id];
    return menuOption;
  }    
});
```

Your corresponding template should look like this in this case:

```
<script data-template-name="menu" type="text/x-handlebars">
<ul>
{{#each option in controller.content.options}}
  <li>{{#linkTo menu option}}{{option.name}}{{/linkTo}}</li>
{{/each}}
</ul>
</script>
```

Comment: The each helper could become shorter like this: {{#each option in options}}. But i am not absolutely sure, if this would work. If you provide a fiddle, we could work on a solution together.

Comment: If I could figure out how to make jsFiddle work with route modification, I would...

Comment: When I tried to put a fiddle together for this question originally, I couldn't get transitionTo to work at all, so I presumed that was a jsFiddle limitation. Anyway, your suggestion (including {{#each option in options}}) has got me out of the hole I was in.  Now I just need to figure out why the transitionTo doesn't call the model method on the MenuRoute, and I'll be all set...

Comment: The model hook is just called when an URL is deserialized (= direct jumo in via URL). So when you jump in URL, the model hook is called. Then its result is used for transitionTo("menu", modelHookResult). That means you need to pass the the same datastructure to transitionTo as it is returned by your model hook implementation.

Comment: So the model hook is just used for making the very first call to transitionTo when your App is entered via URL. Than you are supposed to pass the right contexts to transitionTo.

Answer (score 0):

The error message basically says that view expects either array or array controller as the view's content but receives a generated controller instead(controller is generated when no controller is defined for route). The route's `model` method returns array thus it must be wrapped with appropriate controller - the `ArrayController`. You should define a custom controller for the *menu* route which extends `ArrayController` - this will eliminate the error message.

#### Edit

And about routing: I think you should have defined each of our menu options as a route nested in the *menu* resource, like this:

```
Form.Router.map(function(){
    this.resource( "menu", { path: "/menu/:index_id" }, function () {
        this.route('root');
        this.route('a');
        this.route('b');
        ...
    });
});
```

This will also require defining the *Route* class for each route..

Comment: About the routing, the whole reason I'm doing it this way is because the menu structure is data-driven. I don't know the routes up-front.